# Remove specific cookie in Guzzle response

Tags: php, cookies, httpresponse, guzzle

I would like to remove a specific cookie in a Guzzle response object.

My application uses Slim framework and I make calls to an API with Guzzle. Both Slim and Guzzle implement the Request and Response Interface (Psr7) so I can easily return a Guzzle response in a Slim controller like this :

```
class APIController {

   public function call($request, $response) {
      // Do stuff with $request (check body and params, change url, etc)

      $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
      $response = $client->send($request, []);

      return $response;
   }

}
```

Everything works fine but the API returns a cookie I want to remove. I can remove the whole header with :

```
$response = $response->withoutHeader('Set-Cookie');
```

Is there a native way in Guzzle to remove a specific cookie by name instead of removing the whole header ?